# Event/callback in datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a ListBox of custom items ("EditableTextBlock", a normal TextBlock that, on click, becomes a TextBox and then returns a TextBlock after the edits.)
I want to send an event, or to launch a callback to the parent, inform someway that there have been a successful edit;

In the EditableTextBlock I can have a method like

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
   this.IsInEditMode = false;
   AcceptRenaming(sender, e);
}
```

and I could use that `AcceptRenaming()` to send the information somehow, but
I found that, being the item an DataTemplate, I can't use directly an EventHandler (calling from the parent something like 
`EditTextBlock.RenameEvent += new EventHandler(OnRenameAccepted);`)

I tried to create a RoutedEvent following the tips on [How do you add an Event Trigger to a data template for a business object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422943/how-do-you-add-an-event-trigger-to-a-data-template-for-a-business-object), but I couldn't understand how to register to the EventRegistry to my custom event that I'd create.

What I'm missing here? Or is my approach completely wrong, and there is something else I could/should do?

Thanks in advance

---

ListBox using the EditableTextBlock:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbConfigurationList"
             DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ConfListVM.ObservableConfList}"
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding ConfName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

EditableTextBlock xaml:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditModeTemplate">
            <TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" Loaded="TextBox_Loaded" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
                     Text="{Binding ElementName=EditableText, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DisplayModeTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=EditableText, Path=Text}" >
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Rename" Click="RenameContext_Click"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
             </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EditableTextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditModeTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DisplayModeTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: So you want to throw an event inside your custom class `EditableTextBlock` and then handle the event in the parent?

Comment: Yes (or better, I just want the parent to know that something has been done in the EditableTextBlock), but using a DataTemplated EditableTextBlock

Comment: Why not follow the `TextBox` model, and just bind to the `Text` property, using `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`? Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your scenario, it is difficult to understand what a good answer to your question would be.

Comment: Can you post the xaml with the datatemplate creating your `EdittableTextBlock`?

Comment: Updated with some xamls. Actually, I didn't think I could bind to the PropertyChanged, but how is it different from another event?

Comment: I tried the property "Mode=TwoWay", and now I feel so stupid to have not just told before I just needed to update the source text...